# How to hide numbering when there's one item with ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using AngularJS, HTML, and Bootstrap/CSS to make my web application. I am trying to make an ordered list using the `<ol>` tag with a `<li ng-repeat …>` tag. I want to hide the numbers if there's only one item in the list. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

A snipet of my code:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <ol>
            <li ng-repeat="cog in cogs.Cognitivediagnosis">{{cog}}&nbsp;</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you asking using ol only if there is more than one element?

Answer (score 2):

Add a class with [`ngClass`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass), for instance `ol--no-number`, when there is only one item in the list:

```css
.ol--no-number {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ol ng-class="{'ol--no-number': cogs.Cognitivediagnosis.length == 1}">
    <li ng-repeat="cog in cogs.Cognitivediagnosis">{{cog}}&nbsp;</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @user3783947 You're welcome. Don't forget to set one of the answers as accepted, in order to set the question as resolved :) .

Answer (score 2):

You could do a hack with CSS like this:

```
ol li:last-child {
    list-style:none;
}

ol li + li {
    list-style: inherit!important;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EqJ4a/)